# Ubuntu 22.04 shutting down randomly

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

I've been using Ubuntu for almost 2 years. Since last week my Ubuntu has been shutting down without any reason. I reinstalled Ubuntu and changed SSD to HDD but still the problem exists. The CPU is not overloading(I think), the fan is working properly, no dust.

Is there any way to diagnose the problem (software and hardware)?
Can it be a motherboard problem?

**Laptop specs:**

- Model - Dell Inc. Inspiron 15-3567
- RAM - 12 GB
- Processor - Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- Rom - 256 GB SSD

When I enter `journalctl -r -b -1` this shows :

```
Jan 30 12:51:12 adnan-Inspiron wpa_supplicant[612]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=-100 txrate=6000
Jan 30 12:51:10 adnan-Inspiron wpa_supplicant[612]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-100 txrate=6000
Jan 30 12:50:48 adnan-Inspiron wpa_supplicant[612]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=-99 txrate=6000
Jan 30 12:50:47 adnan-Inspiron wpa_supplicant[612]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-76 noise=-99 txrate=6000
Jan 30 12:50:32 adnan-Inspiron wpa_supplicant[612]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=-99 txrate=6000
Jan 30 12:50:30 adnan-Inspiron wpa_supplicant[612]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=-99 txrate=6000
```

(Shut Down at 12:53)

Comment: What's near the beginning of your `journalctl -r -b -1`?

Comment: Random generally means a memory error. So start by running memtest and see if that shows errors. There will be notices in /var/log/ if  the crash is not random.

Comment: @DanielT I updated the question. In which log should I look?

Comment: Those logs don't look normal because it looks that the system died so fast that it didn't know what hit it. Please confirm that you did not see the usual {Stop*,Unmount,Remov*,Closed}, and the important "systemd-logind[817]: System is powering down." and "The system will power off now!" lines. The only unlikely fixable cases are a rogue app running `sudo poweroff --force` or low battery / overheating. To me, it looks identical to the CPU losing power or the BIOS forcing an immediate shutdown

Comment: Based on your journalctl, it is unlikely that anything related got written to /var/log. So just look in BIOS to see if there are any thermal / battery / (30/15 minute) timeout settings that look wrong. Then use memtest like Rinzwind said